# My typescript code is not showing on Javascript file. It runs without any error on my console it just doesn't show the code on JS file

Tags: typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmCcX.png)
My typescript code is not showing on Javascript file.It runs without any error on my console it just doesn't show the code on JS file. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing posts that best invite helpful guidance from the community.  Also, as a reminder, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). This post is missing some critical context that will be needed for others to answer it. What is the code in the TS source file you are transpile? What are you running to transpile it?  What is the output of the transpilation command? It might also make sense to share your config for the transpiler.  Share this info and you'll probably get better replies.

Comment: Please post your code as text in a code block. This will assist others in answering your question and will not rely on the image URL staying valid.